# Al darle a submit, no se conecta correctamente y muestra una página en blanco con el código

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, xampp

He seguido un tutorial, para aprender algo de *PHP* (cambiando algunas cosillas):

He usado *XAMPP* como contenedor y he creado un formulario que, al darle al `submit`, debería guardar la información en la tabla que he creado.

Esta es la info de la tabla:

[image: Tabla]

Al darle a guardar en mi formulario, me sale el código de lo que debería hacer,
aquí os lo dejo también:

```
<?php
//conectar con el servidor
$conectar=@mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
//verificamos la coneccion
if(!$conectar)
{
    echo"No se pudo conectar con el servidor";
}
else
{
    $base = mysql_select_db('pruebas');
    if (!$base)
    {
        echo"No se encontro la base de datos";
    }
}
//declaracion y recuperacion variables
$id = 1;
&nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$cp = $_POST['codigopostal'];
$poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
$provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
//sentencia de sql
$sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$id','$nombre','$direccion','$cp','$poblacion','$provincia','$telefono','$email')";
//ejectar sentencia sql
$ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);
//verificamos la ejecucion
if (!$ejecutar)
{
    echo"hubo algun error";
}
else
{
    echo"datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
}
?>
```

Uso *Windows 8.1 64 bits* y *XAMPP v3.2.2* y si necesitáis más info de algo, preguntaré.

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. El código debes escribirlo en formato código en el cuerpo de la pregunta, no en imagenes

Comment: Con todo respeto, has empezado con mal pie tu aprendizaje. Actualmente hay muchos tutoriales obsoletos, de hecho el que has seguido, parece ser uno de ellos. Por ejemplo, hace una mezcla entre mysqli : `mysqli_connect ...` y mysql: `$ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);` no es lo mismo ni es igual. Todas las funciones `mysql.*` han sido declaradas obsoletas y no existen a partir de PHP 7. Yo te recomendaría usar la extensión PDO, ofrece más posibilidades para manejar los datos y es más facil de usar. [Éste puede ser un buen comienzo](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php), pero no suficiente.

Comment: Hola al parecer te falta cerrar el php ejemplo `<?php codigo ?>`

Comment: Para A.Cedano: lo del primer connect que  pone mysqli lo cambié yo, debido a que estaba probando cosa y me olvidé de dejarlo como estaba... ates era mysql_connect... y no sé como mirar la versión php que uso

Para Kevin: el ?> si que está, pero esta fuera del código que he enseñado (y por alguna razon sale por debajo del código que he pegado)

Comment: Le has puesto la extensión al archivo del php el .php ? Y tienes en el formulario <form method="POST" action="nombreArchivoPhp.php">

Answer (score 1):

No funciona porque no tienes php funcionando con apache.

Puedes comprobarlo haciendo un archivo php con el siguiente contenido.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Si no te imprime nada más que esas líneas es lo que te digo.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/800912574da88f2c158db357a729d353

Me copia una página con con el código php (sin hacer nada).

Comment: Yo también creo que esta sea la respuesta. @user44330 revisa que tengas bien instalado el php y hazlo de la manera que está en esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu versión del XAMPP, tienes v3.2.2, es peligroso!
Te recomiendo que te actualices para estar al día con Apache y PHP
Eso es porque hoy en día se usa Php 7.1 de en adelante, porque hubo muchos cambios.
Saludos!

Comment: No creo que esta sea una respuesta que de solución al problema, es más bien una recomendación por lo que debes ponerlo como comentario. Pronto tendrás suficientes puntos de reputación para poder publicar comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ok user44330 lo asumo estaba fuera, agregando otra respuesta a lo mejor mysql_query() no te esta reconociendo la consulta insert

```
$sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$id','$nombre','$direccion','$cp','$poblacion','$provincia','$telefono','$email')";
```

podrias probar agregando

```
$sql="INSERT INTO datos (id,nombre, ...,email)//campos de la tabla datos

VALUES('$id','$nombre', '$direccion','$cp','$poblacion','$provincia','$telefono','$email')";
```